# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator Seam weblogic 10.3

Tags: java, hibernate, seam, weblogic-10.x

I have a big problem with Hibernate (use with seam) on weblogic 10.3.

When I publish my application, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.util.ResourceBundle, org.hibernate.validator.MessageInterpolator, java.util.Map, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager)
```

I read on the web that this error can come from compatibily between hibernate jar. But, I read the matrix and I have the good jar with good version (hibernate-validator 3.1, hibernate-search 3.1, hibernate core 3.3.0)

I haven't idea to resolve this problem. Someone can help me ?

Thanks.

PS: Here is the full stack trace:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1373)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:468)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:117)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:635)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:16)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:162)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:140)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:106)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:143)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:820)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1227)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:436)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:181)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:12)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:67)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.util.ResourceBundle, org.hibernate.validator.MessageInterpolator, java.util.Map, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2706)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:352)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1148)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1226)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:159)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:854)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:191)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:253)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:125)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:60)
        at org.jboss.seam.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory.java:81)
        at org.jboss.seam.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.startup(EntityManagerFactory.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
        at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:144)
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.callComponentMethod(Component.java:2257)
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.callCreateMethod(Component.java:2172)
        at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2132)
        at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.startup(Contexts.java:304)
        at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.startup(Contexts.java:278)
        at org.jboss.seam.contexts.ServletLifecycle.endInitialization(ServletLifecycle.java:116)
        at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.init(Initialization.java:740)
        at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener.contextInitialized(SeamListener.java:36)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:465)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:175)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1785)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3005)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1371)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:468)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:117)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:635)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
        at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:16)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:162)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:140)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:106)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:143)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:820)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1227)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:436)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:181)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:12)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:67)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
    >
```

Comment: I tried this, many time ;) and nothing has changed

Answer (score 13):

It happens when you use newer version of Hibernate in your application while pre-packaged hibernate jars (that come with jboss server) are of older version. For details on how to properly upgrade your application server's hibernate jars, read [this](http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com/2008/08/how-to-upgrade-hibernate-in-jboss.html).

Comment: brilliant! How can you know that?

Comment: Because i've gone through this pain.

Comment: just a little question, do you know the best way to avoid conflict? It seems the error when conflict happens doesn't give much inFormation

Comment: These kind of issues do arise when we use various frameworks together. But the art of guess-work comes with experience :)

Answer (score 12):

I solved this problem adding this two properties in my hibernate config.

```
<property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</property> 
<property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
```

Comment: That's it !! Worked for me with Hibernate 3.6.0.Final and JBoss 4.2.1.GA. Many many thanks !!

Comment: You saved my day... how did you found this out ?

Comment: is this hibernate config file is present in server ?

Comment: No, the hibernate config should be in your resources folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to hit this issue on Weblogic Server, I solved this problem on Weblogic 10.3.0.0 with placing the package `org.hibernate` to `prefer-application-packages` at `weblogic-application.xml` in the EAR:

```
<weblogic-application>
   <prefer-application-packages>
      <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
   </prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```

With a properly built application this will prevent Weblogic Server loading the older, conflicting library from the server's classpath and make it work as expected.