# Deployment problem on JBOSS server 5.0.1.GA

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, deployment, jboss5.x

When I am deploying the same application on Tomcat 6.0 and Glassfish 3.0 it is working fine
but on JBOSS server I am getting the below error. Please give specific solution.How can i programatically remove the hibernate-validator.jar of jBoss making some entry in xml files as I can't remove that jar from jBoss manually everytime....

Stack Trace :

```
20:25:07,187 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/Taher
20:25:07,281 INFO  [[/Taher]] Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
20:25:07,281 INFO  [ContextLoader] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
20:25:07,328 INFO  [XmlWebApplicationContext] Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@ed7df5: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Tue Nov 23 20:25:07 GMT+05:30 2010]; root of context hierarchy
20:25:07,390 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/ApplicationContext.xml]
20:25:07,734 INFO  [XmlWebApplicationContext] Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@ed7df5]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@189ff76
20:25:07,781 INFO  [DefaultListableBeanFactory] Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@189ff76: defining beans [dataSource,sessionFactory,transactionManager,hibernateTemplate,hibernateInterceptor,TblActivityMasterDao]; root of factory hierarchy
20:25:08,281 INFO  [Version] Hibernate Annotations 3.3.1.GA
20:25:08,296 INFO  [Environment] Hibernate 3.2.5
20:25:08,296 INFO  [Environment] hibernate.properties not found
20:25:08,296 INFO  [Environment] Bytecode provider name : cglib
20:25:08,296 INFO  [Environment] using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
20:25:08,437 INFO  [AnnotationBinder] Binding entity from annotated class: com.mycompany.taher.TblActivityMaster
20:25:08,484 INFO  [EntityBinder] Bind entity com.mycompany.taher.TblActivityMaster on table tbl_ActivityMaster
20:25:08,734 INFO  [DefaultListableBeanFactory] Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@189ff76: defining beans [dataSource,sessionFactory,transactionManager,hibernateTemplate,hibernateInterceptor,TblActivityMasterDao]; root of factory hierarchy
20:25:08,734 ERROR [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/ApplicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.util.ResourceBundle, org.hibernate.validator.MessageInterpolator, java.util.Map, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4393)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:312)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:144)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
        at $Proxy36.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)

        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:698)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:290)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:221)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.util.ResourceBundle, org.hibernate.validator.MessageInterpolator, java.util.Map, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:370)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1115)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:673)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
        ... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.util.ResourceBundle, org.hibernate.validator.MessageInterpolator, java.util.Map, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2706)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:357)
        ... 83 more
20:25:09,187 ERROR [[/Taher]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/ApplicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.util.ResourceBundle, org.hibernate.validator.MessageInterpolator, java.util.Map, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4393)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:312)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:144)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
        at $Proxy36.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
        at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:698)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:290)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:221)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.util.ResourceBundle, org.hibernate.validator.MessageInterpolator, java.util.Map, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:370)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1115)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:673)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
        ... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.util.ResourceBundle, org.hibernate.validator.MessageInterpolator, java.util.Map, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2706)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:357)
        ... 83 more
20:25:09,687 ERROR [StandardContext] Error listenerStart
20:25:09,687 ERROR [StandardContext] Context [/Taher] startup failed due to previous errors
20:25:09,687 INFO  [[/Taher]] Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Comment: Try to read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097567/jboss-and-different-versions-of-hibernate It was a salvation for me!

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem adding this two properties in my hibernate config.

```
<property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</property> 
<property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9269059/419) to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead.

Answer (score 2):

the likely cause of this is that JBoss has its own internal copy of Hibernate, along with Hibernate Search and Hibernate Validator.

If your application also has its own copy of Hibernate in its `lib` directory, and this is a different version to that held inside JBoss, then the risk is that they'll clash.  Specifically, Hibernate will attempt to auto-discover the Validator and Search libraries, and if there is a version clash, this is the result.

The simplest thing to do is to disable the auto-discovery of Hibernate Search and Validator, by adding these to your hibernate properties inside the application:

```
hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners=false
hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners=false
```

Comment: No dear by adding above property also the error remains same. I have build my project in Maven :(

Answer (score 2):

This issue is caused since JBoss is shipped with hibernate 3.3 libraries. I had the same error message and fixed it by deleting `hibernate-validator.jar` from `{JBOSS_HOME}/common/lib/` folder. Just make sure that your application is shipped with correct version of `hibernate-validator.jar` file.

I know this is not *actually a solution* but I have gone through JBoss forum threads [573076](http://community.jboss.org/message/573076) and [621877](http://community.jboss.org/message/621877); tried the `jboss-classloading.xml` solution as described in [here](http://phytodata.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/demystifying-the-jboss5-jboss-classloading-xml-file/).. None of these helped me resolve the issue..

Further materials on jboss-classloading.xml, in case any one needs are [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jboss-microcontainer-classloading),[here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?73879-Problem-with-Hibernate-Annotation-while-using-JBoss) and [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1011790).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is no hibernate on the classpath of jboss. Jboss typically comes with hibernate libraries built in which can cause these kinds of conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Only remove, following set of jar files from common/lib
1. hibernate-annotations.jar
2. hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
3. hibernate-entitymanager.jar
4. hibernate-validator.jar