# Spring 3.0.5 Webapp runs great in tomcat.... will not start in JBoss EAP 5.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss5.x

Spring 3.0.5 Webapp runs great in tomcat.... will not start in JBoss EAP 5.1

I have a very easy webapp that I made using Eclipse, Spring 3.05 that was runnig in tomcat6.1 without   any issues and my firm is moving to Jboss EAP 5.1 and I am getting the following error.

```
Jboss EAP 5.1 Error.
16:29:20,695 INFO  [STDOUT] [DEBUG,Configuration] processing association property references
16:29:20,695 INFO  [STDOUT] [DEBUG,Configuration] processing foreign key constraints
16:29:20,798 INFO  [STDOUT] [INFO,DefaultListableBeanFactory] Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@784f63b5: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,requestController,memberInquiryServiceImpl,articleDao,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,jspViewResolver,dataSource,requestTrackerConfig,sessionFactory,hibernateTransactionManager]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@79063635
16:29:20,834 INFO  [STDOUT] [ERROR,DispatcherServlet] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.uftwf.service.MemberInquiryService org.uftwf.controller.RequestController.memberInquiryService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'memberInquiryServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.uftwf.dao.MemberInquiryDao org.uftwf.service.MemberInquiryServiceImpl.memberInquiryDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'articleDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.uftwf.dao.MemberInquiryDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.util.ResourceBundle, org.hibernate.validator.MessageInterpolator, java.util.Map, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deployment problem on JBOSS server 5.0.1.GA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257462/deployment-problem-on-jboss-server-5-0-1-ga)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Hibernate Validator in your code, which conflicts with Hibernate Validator bundled in JBoss, and their versions do not match.

Every JavaEE container has some property to make the class-loader search for classes in project classes before container libraries.

I don't know the tag (in JBoss specific deployment descriptor), just look it up in JBoss documents.