# JBoss 5 - Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator

Tags: spring, hibernate, migration, jboss5.x

I keep getting that exception when I run JBoss. I'm in the process of migrating an application from JBoss 4.2.3 to JBoss 5.

First I had to migrate from Spring 2.5 to Spring 3.0.3, then from spring-jpa to spring-orm due to exceptions I was getting and solutions I found on google.

But now I've got that one and I'm not able to solve it. I'm also using Hibernate 3.5.4 Final.

This is the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.util.ResourceBundle, org.hibernate.validator.MessageInterpolator, java.util.Map, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2706)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.applyHibernateValidatorLegacyConstraintsOnDDL(AnnotationConfiguration.java:443)
    ... 106 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deployment problem on JBOSS server 5.0.1.GA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257462/deployment-problem-on-jboss-server-5-0-1-ga)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a conflict between Hibernate versions, as JBoss 5+ comes bundled with Hibernate.  Make sure that you only have one version of Hibernate in your server (check the /lib dir).